# Parse query- saving pfobject and children with one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a fairly typical comment-post app I'm trying to build for fun. My problem is when I save a comment to an existing post (with a one post - many comments relationship), the comment is saved and understands its relationship to the post, but the post does not know about the comment.

What I want:

```
Posts: post "Foo" | comments: "X", "Y" | other columns
Comments:
comment "X" | post "Foo" | ...
comment "Y" | post "Foo" | ...
```

Right now:
The comments look good, but the posts are missing the one-to-many relationship

```
Posts: post "Foo" | <NOTHING> | other columns
```

I've tried two different ways of saving comments to posts:

1) Create comment as child of Post, save Post. According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651516/parse-saving-related-objects), this is fine, and indeed the comment is saved, even though we perform the save on the post object. But the post doesn't see the comment as child.

```
// Inside comment class
let pfComment = PFObject()
pfPost.addObject(pfComment, forKey: "comments") // Add the comment to the post
```

2) Do a saveAll on both comment and post, which gives me two comments, as the one saved by the post is seen as a separate new object from the other comment

```
// Same pfComment as above,
PFObject.saveAllInBackground([pfPost, pfComment], block: ...
```

What gives? Parse [docs and questions](https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-code-efficient-hierarchy-saving) are unhelpful!

Answer (score 2):

I think when you're initiating and saving a PFObject, [you need to be explicit about what kind of object you're dealing with](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-saving/iOS). So for your comment object, you could say pfComment = PFObject(className: "Comment"). Now when you save it, Parse will know what you want to save.

I believe I accomplished your goal by creating a Post class with an array for comments like so:

[image: Post Class]

I also made a simple comment class that has a string for message:

[image: Comment Class]

From here, I was able to put the code together to add comments to the post's array.

```
    var post = PFObject(className:"Post")
    var comment = PFObject(className:"PostComment")
    comment["message"] = "New Message"

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("fu8gCbYVeI") {
        (result: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            post = result
        } else { }
    }

    post.addObject(comment, forKey: "comments")

    PFObject.saveAll([comment, post])
```

That should save the comments to the post as Pointers to the actual comment objects.